# how to feed variable from IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, indexeddb

I am trying to use the internal storage IndexedDB browser, rather than the localStorage.
I encounter several problems with asynchronous access. I would like to get more data stored in multiple objectstore and perform processing with data sets from the database.

To make a simple example, it could be:

```
var product = getProductById('xxx');
var countryTax = getCountryTax('FR');
var storeDetailed = getStoreDetailed('xxx');
var productPrice = product.price * countryTax.Tax * storeDetailed.margin;
```

With asynchronous access it gives:

```
getProductById('xxx').onComplete = function (product) {
        getCountryTax('FR').onComplete = function (product, countryTax) {
              getStoreDetailed('xxx').onComplete =function(product, countryTax, storeDetailed) {
                   var productPrice = product.price * countryTax.Tax * storeDetailed.margin;
              }
         }
}
```

This sounds very complicated and the code has a high adhesion to the storage method.

Almost all examples encountered feed the html page with the results of the reading base.

From my side I would like to feed variables and perform treatments with the data.
Do you have an idea, please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just want to use variables from a closure scope. That's not a big deal, you can easily access the variables of a outer function (like `getProductById`) in an inner function (like `getCountryTax`).

Your only problem is, that you define variables with the same name in the local scope. These will have priority and will be `undefined` unless it is set by the caller (even if there is a assigned variable in the closure scope with this name). Here is how you could use the closure scope variables in your example:

```
getProductById('xxx').onComplete = function (product) {
        getCountryTax('FR').onComplete = function (countryTax) { // removed product
              // here you can access product from closure and countryTax from local scope
              getStoreDetailed('xxx').onComplete = function(storeDetailed) { // removed arguments, too
                   // here you can access product and countryTax from closure
                   // and storeDetailed from local scope
                   var productPrice = product.price * countryTax.Tax * storeDetailed.margin;
              }
         }
}
```